# How to update DB from oracle 12c to oracle 19c

Tags: dspace

I am using DSpace 6.x with Oracle 12.1.0.2.0. And recently, we would like to upgrade the oracle db from 12c to 19c. Would should we do in order to using oracle 19c and keep in existing DSpace version?